# How do I complete Python3 with YouCompleteMe?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, filetype-python

I'm using YouCompleteMe to do omni complete.

Most of these are fine. But when I want to complete Python3, there is something wrong. It only can complete python2.

For example,

```
import urllib # Python2 & Python3 mod

urllib.
```

I want to complete to `urllib.request.Request`, but the completion menu doesn't have it. It is the same as Python2's `urlopen`. (In Python3, it is `urllib.request.urlopen`, but now is `urllib.urlopen`.)

I have installed `jedi` with both pip and pip3 ( `import jedi` can be done in Python3 and Python2 )

I also have set `let g:ycm_python_binary_path = '/usr/local/bin/python3'`
 in `.vimrc`.

But it seems to have no effect.

Comment: When did you last update YCM?

Comment: @muru Last month

Comment: Python3 completion support was also added [last month](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/295), so perhaps your last update was before that? If it wasn't, please report it as an issue on YCM's Github issue tracker.

Comment: @muru Let me update it again. If it has the same problem, I will report it..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to update YCM and recompile it.

Now, it is fine.

Python3 support was added for last month and I just updated YCM last month.